# Trying to add authorization to my api with swagger

Tags: c#, api, authentication, swagger

im trying to add authorization to my api, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

There is my current code of program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using SA.Entities;
using SA.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<MongoDBSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MongoDBService>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = " ApiKey must appear in header",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Name = "XApiKey",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Scheme = "ApiKeyScheme"
    });
    var key = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Reference = new OpenApiReference
        {
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
            Id = "ApiKey"
        },
        In = ParameterLocation.Header
    };
    var requirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        { key, new List<string>()}
    };
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(requirement);
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");;

app.Run();
```

When I try to request something from swagger without authorization, I always get a 200 - Success.
[image]
it should be 401 - Unauthorized like in [this](https://gowthamcbe.com/2022/02/21/swagger-ui-for-api-key-authentication-flow-with-net-core-6/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the [source code](https://github.com/gowthamece/ApiKeyAuthentication) of the tutorial you will see that you also need to create the middleware and register it using `app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();` in `Program.cs`